# Date picker as input to countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' });
  } );
  </script>

<script language="JavaScript">


TargetDate ="2016/11/25";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = -1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "Expired!";
</script>

<body>
<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<script language="JavaScript" src="//scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want date picker as input to countdown days.(If user selects the date from date picker,that should be an input for countdown).I don't want to put date manually in countdown.Please help me out.I would appreciate for your good solutions.

Comment: you cant do this because the library `countdown.js` you are using is written in such a way that even if you change the content of targetDate it will not affect the timer. because targetDate is set on page load. so only solution is to bring the contents of `countdown.js` to your file and change it accordingly.

Comment: Thanx.Is there any other Code to Countdown days for users input??

Comment: Please check my answer i have given an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this because the library `countdown.js` you are using is written in such a way that even if you change the content of `targetDate` it will not affect the timer. because `targetDate` is set on page load. so only solution is to bring the contents of `countdown.js` to your file and change it accordingly. I suggest you have to use any other(good) library or write your own from scratch.

jQuery.countdown is an easy to use simple jquery plugin for the same. I have created an example for you as per your requirement.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.2.0/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

         $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate:1,dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' });
         });

         // on changing date initilize the countdown again
         $("#datepicker").change(function(){
            init($(this).val());
         })

         function init(dt){
            $('#clock').countdown(dt).on('update.countdown', function(event) {
                var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
                  + '<span>%-w</span> week%!w '
                  +'<span>%-d</span> day%!d '
                  + '<span>%H</span> hr '
                  + '<span>%M</span> min '
                  + '<span>%S</span> sec'));
            });
         }

         //initilize counter on load with some default date
         init("2016/11/25");

      });
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
      <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
      <!-- div which shows the result -->
      <div id="clock"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want more customization please have a look at the documentation.

http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html

Comment: I don't want countdown days that should start from init("  /   /  "). But i want countdown that should start from user selected date from datepicker. Advance Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Datepicker has onSelect event, you can do your stuff there eg:

```
$("#sample").datepicker({
    picker: "#paymentDate", 
    onSelect : function(y, m, i){  
        // your code goes here 
    },
});
```

Comment: Date picker is working fine.If user picks a date from date picker that should be an input to countdown "TargetDate"..How can i do ?

Comment: Basically you need selected Date which user has selected in Datepicker. and after you have it you can  add your logic ie pass it as input to countdown. to do that you can use onSelect  event

Answer (score 0):

You didn't made an event for date selection, I have edited the code, hope things are upto your expectations. (Y)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>


      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    
<body>
<script>
  $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
          dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
          onSelect: function() 
                    {
                     var date=$(this).val().toString();
//alert('on select triggered '+date);
     
                     TargetDate = date;
                     CountActive = true;
                     CountStepper = -1;
                     LeadingZero = true;
                     DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
                     FinishMessage = "Expired!";
 document.write("<script src='//scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js'><\/script>");
        },
   });
 });

</script>

    <h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    

</body>
</html>
```